# Why doesn't everyone applaud Harry at the end of DH2 film?

Tags: harry-potter

At the very end of the film, when Harry walks through the devastated halls of HogWarts and everyone is gathered tending to the wounded and dead and comforting each other, I found it very strange that other than Hagrid giving Harry a hug, nobody else seemed to care that Potter was there.  Given that he just destroyed Voldemort, and given standard movie tropes of how a "the good guys won!" finale scene works, I fully expected everyone to cheer Harry or rush up to thank him or something... instead everyone just kind of glanced up and then went back to what they were doing.  This seemed very weird and anti-climatic.  What's behind that story decision?  Is there something in the book that clarifies it?

I get that probably everyone was sad and exhausted, and maybe a few had been skewed by Voldemort's claim that Harry was letting his friends die to protect him in a cowardly fashion -- but surely most remembered that Voldemort was out to get all the muggle-borns as well, and (since news travels fast at Hogwarts) many probably knew that Harry had let himself be *killed* in order to destroy Voldemort... Just seems odd.

Comment: In the movie theater I was watching the movie, everyone clapped.

Answer (score 5):

The final scene is quite different between the movie and book. For one, the duel between Harry and Voldemort takes place in the Great Hall, where they are surrounded by Harry's friends and allies. Here's the book, moments after Voldemorts corpse (yes, corpse, he dies like any normal man in the book) hits the floor.

> One shivering second of silence, the shock of the moment suspend: and
>   then the tumult broke around Harry as the screams and the cheers and
>   the roars of the watchers rent the air. The fierce new sun dazzled the
>   windows as they thundered toward him, and the first to reach him were
>   Ron and Hermione, and it was their arms that were wrapped around him,
>   their incomprehensible shouts that deafened him. Then Ginny, Neville,
>   and Luna were there, and then all the Weasleys and Hagrid, and
>   Kingsley and McGonagall and Flitwick and Spout, and Harry could not
>   hear a word that anyone was shouting, nor tell whose hands were
>   seizing him, pulling him, trying to hug some part of him, hundreds of
>   them pressing in, all of them determined to touch the Boy Who Lived,
>   the reason it was over at last—

So yes, cheering and such does indeed happen in the books.

Answer (score 5):

They don't all run up to congratulate or thank Harry because they have other things to do. As you said, they are all tending to the wounded and dead. Keep in mind that almost everyone on the Order's side of the Battle of Hogwarts were friends, and many of them were family. A lot of their friends and family have been killed, so even though they won, they aren't in a celebratory mood.

As I see it, it would be a lot odder if everyone *did* start cheering, given their losses.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I liked the books version way better than the movie's. 
However, in the movie, the scene in question clearly shows everyone morning the cost of the battle.

There's sad music, rows and rows of corpses, most of whom we know, and even more being wept on or mourned by someone we know.

And the linchpin of the scene is the entire oversized weasly family, including Ron, one of the big three, sobbing and screaming over the death of funny and awesome Fred (or was it George). Even if I liked the way the book did it better, that was not a scene for clapping and cheering.

Comment: Totally get that.  But WHY would the movie do it that way?

Comment: That wasn't your question. Your question was "why was nobody clapping/cheering"